# Can we call a anonymous function at run time?

Tags: javascript

I was trying to run this function. Is it possible to do ??

```
(function(a,b){
    return a+b;
});
var ans = (function(a , b))(4,5);
console.log('ii '+ans);
```

Comment: were you able to run?..you should have answered on your own

Comment: what are you trying to do.. unless you have a reference you can't

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )` > No you can't. At least not like that.

Comment: `var ans = (function(a , b))(4,5);`  has no function body.

Comment: I am not able to run that is why i am asking. That can i do somethng like this??

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can!

```js
var ans = function (a, b) { return a + b; }(4, 5);
document.write(ans);
```